# Passing a const pointer to a struct vs pass by value

Tags: c, performance, pointers, struct, coding-style

What is recommended to use, passing a structure as a pointer to `const` i.e.

```
int doCalculations(const MyStruct* my_struct);
```

or passing the `struct` by value, as in,

```
int doCalculations(MyStruct my_struct);
```

and why?

In C++ I recall reading somewhere that passing references to `const` should be used when the `struct`/`Class` has a non-trivial constructor. In C although there are no constructors, I imagine it would still take some time to make a local copy of the `struct`.

Comment: It depends on how your function is going to use the `struct`. If it has to change something inside the `struct` you need a pointer. Otherwise passing the `struct` itself is preferable.

Comment: @Kninnug passing by value uses unnecessary amounts of stack.  More common guidance would be that you should pass by pointer to const - `const MyStruct*` - when `sizeof(MyStruct) > x` for some smallish value of `x`

Comment: @simonc: I guess you meant 'pointer to const', not 'const pointer'...

Comment: @a1ex07 Yes, thanks, I meant `const MyStruct*`. I've corrected my comment now

Comment: Recommendation will largely depend upon the size of the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to modify your struct then you obviously have to pass it by pointer.

If you do not intend to modify your struct then it is still general practice to pass by pointer to avoid unnecessary copying. A pointer will take up `sizeof(void *)` memory, but may be passed by register (thus not using stack memory at all).

Passing a struct by value will almost always make a copy of it on the stack.

Two scenarios where you have to choose:

- If your struct may be modified by an external force (i.e. it has `volatile`) fields then you will probably want to pass it by pointer in order to always have the most up to date version.
- If your struct may cease to exist during execution of your function (e.g. another thread `free`s that memory) then you will obviously have to make a copy of it (pass by value).

Comment: *If you intend to modify your struct then you obviously have to pass it by pointer.* and *If you do not intend to modify your struct then it is general practice to pass by pointer to avoid unnecessary copying.* I don't understand the difference between these two sentences.

Comment: @PHIfounder general practice != requirement. But i have clarified it a bit.

Comment: @SergeyL. Is your last point regarding struct ceasing to exist purely theoretical?

Comment: @Pacerier No, but those cases are generally intentional and programmer controlled. Example: producer-consumer threading on a stack. One you "consume" an element another thread will soon overwrite that memory, so you are better off with copying.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why passing a structure by value is not advised:

> 1). The amount of time taken to copy the structure contents into a new
>   temporary variable.
>
> 2). The amount of stack space that would be wasted, especially if the
>   structure is large.

Hence using a pointer to const is a much more viable option.